# How to test handle_info/2 in Phoenix LiveView?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, functional-testing, phoenix-channels, phoenix-live-view

Greetings Phoenix LiveView Wizards!

## Context

We have a basic LiveView counter app: https://github.com/dwyl/phoenix-liveview-counter-tutorial 
The code is very simple: [`/live/counter.ex`](https://github.com/dwyl/phoenix-liveview-counter-tutorial/blob/master/lib/live_view_counter_web/live/counter.ex) 
The App works as expected, see: https://live-view-counter.herokuapp.com

The test file is: [`test/live_view_counter_web/live/counter_test.exs`](https://github.com/dwyl/phoenix-liveview-counter-tutorial/blob/master/test/live_view_counter_web/live/counter_test.exs) 
We are stuck with trying to invoke the `handle_info/2` function in a test. 
So we have code in our project that is untested. Which is undesirable. 
See: https://codecov.io/gh/dwyl/phoenix-liveview-counter-tutorial/src/master/lib/live_view_counter_web/live/counter.ex

[image: counter-not-covered]

We have read through the official docs https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveViewTest.html 
but have not been able to understand how to do it. What are we missing?

We *really* want to use `LiveView` in our "real" projects, but we want to ensure that our `LiveView` apps are *fully* tested.

## Question

How do we write a **test** to invoke the `handle_info/2` function?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveViewTest.html#module-testing-events) is unclear?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for your quick reply. It was unclear how to setup the test file and then invoke the `handle_event/3` function. But from re-reading the docs, it appears we do not invoke the function _directly_ rather it is invoked _indirectly_ by the `render_click(view, :inc)` (_thank you for helping us come to this realisation ..._)

Comment: `handle_event/3` is a callback for the message arrived to the LV process, which means one does not ever want to test it via direct call.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the challenge of testing the `handle_info/2` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much research, trial and error, error, error (iteration), we came up with the following test:

```
test "handle_info/2", %{conn: conn} do
  {:ok, view, disconnected_html} = live(conn, "/")
  assert disconnected_html =~ "Count: 0"
  assert render(view) =~ "Count: 0"
  send(view.pid, %{payload: %{ val: 1 }})
  assert render(view) =~ "Count: 1"
end
```

Thanks to @daniel for pointing us in the direction of the `send/2` function. 
and @AlekseiMatiushkin for patiently asking probing questions above. 
Thanks to @chrismccord for the insight: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-test-handle-info-2-in-phoenix-liveview/30070/7

Answer (score 2):

[`handle_info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_info/2) is a general behavior of [`Genserver`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html). If you read documentation, you can find:

> Besides the synchronous and asynchronous communication provided by
>   [`call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#call/3) and [`cast/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#cast/2), "regular" messages sent by functions such as
>   [`Kernel.send/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#send/2), [`Process.send_after/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#send_after/4) and similar, can be handled inside
>   the [`handle_info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_info/2) callback.

So you can send either of those as long as you know the `pid` of the process.

Comment: Thanks for pointing us in the right direction @Daniel  (answer upvoted)